# how do I edit country-state-select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I was thinking of customizing this ruby on rails gem in my app. Something like :having a data for a particular country and it's locals. When that country is selected in the above gem I want the data I have differently for that country to be used in the app. Is this possible and for the records I don't know whether to have a different database for the particular country. For more emphasis see below.

Using the gem country-state-select...

```
if country == Russia then
  # the data from the country would be used..
  # should the data for this country be in database?
else
  # the flow of the gem still works for other countries
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want visitors to be able to edit/delete/add data for the country then you will definitely need to have a database. But otherwise you don't have to use a database column for each country. You can render partials like

```
if country == Russia 
render 'russia'

elsif country == Germany
render 'germany'
...
```

Other than that you can also use jQuery to accomplish this.

```
    $(document).on('change', '.country_select', function() {
     if ($(this).val('russia')) (
      $('.show_text_here_div').text('blablablal information about russia');
     )
     else if ($(this).val('Germany')) (
      $('.show_text_here_div').text('blablablal information about germany');
     )
    });
```

Comment: No they are not going to  create anything,except for them to select from the list. But where  should  the  data of this country go: The states and the locals?

Comment: Well as i said you can put them in partials '_Russia.html.erb', '_Germany.html.erb' etc.. And then render the partial based on the value of the selected country.